# Solved: New install - white font on white background

Tags: fonts

New install of EMACS on arco linux, and new user. All fonts are white on a white background and cannot be seen unless they are highlighted, which makes the tutorial useless. How can I fix this? I have not done any tweaking or customizing.

Edit: In response to Fran Burstall's comment,`emacs -Q` corrects the issue. I am using GUI Emacs. So, should I just always run `emacs -Q`, or is there a configuration I can adjust to permanently solve this?

Edit: So, both `emacs -q` and `emacs --no-site-file` startup emacs with the problem of white against white. I checked my `.Xresources` but there are no instances of emacs in it.

Edit: Trying out @NickD's suggestion, running all various combinations of `emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --no-x-resources` narrowed it down pretty quick. As @Fran-Burstall had suggested at first, XResources seems to be the culprit, as only removing `--no-x-resources` fixed the issue in all iterations. My XResources file is stock for my distribution. Here is the pastebin link to my XResources file: https://pastebin.com/kKVzaDsv

Also, there was no `default.el`

Edit: @NickD's suggestion to comment out the foreground color in the `.Xresources` did the trick! Porblem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just checking: do you get this behaviour if you invoke emacs as `emacs -Q`?  Is this in a terminal or is it GUI emacs?

Comment: `emacs -Q` is a (very often useful) debugging method. It starts up `emacs` without any [initialization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), so the fact that you don't see the problem means that it is not a problem with emacs: it is only a problem with the initialization. Now you have to figure out exactly which part of the initialization is at fault. As @FranBurstall suggests, if you do `emacs -q` and *still* do not see the problem, then your personal initialization file is at fault. That way, you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Try `emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --no-x-resources`. I assume that is going to work (it is equivalent to `-Q` I believe). Now try eliminating each *one* of the three options, keeping the other two, and see what works and what does not. Then try with only one option in turn and see what works and what does not. Be systematic, make a table with the results, and add the table to your question.

Comment: In a working emacs (presumably with `-Q`), also check if there is a `default.el` file with `M-x locate-library RET default RET`. If there is one, you might want to either add it to your answer if it is relatively short, or post it to a pastebin service and post a link to it: this is a file that might be provided with your distribution and might  or might not exist.

Comment: It's probably that `*.foreground` setting, since everything else seems to be specific to some other application. Try commenting it out or changing to a different color. But in any case, you can always run it with `--no-x-resources`: modify the desktop file if you start emacs by clicking on an icon; or make an alias `alias emacs='/usr/bin/emacs --no-x-resources'` (adjust the path to your own circumstances) if you start it from the command line (or do both to cover both possibilities).

Comment: Please open an issue with Arco Linux: they should not be setting the foreground like this in every user's `.Xresources` file (assuming that you did not change it yourself of course). This is going to bite other users of Arco Linux so you should tell them about it so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet as I'm a new user. In response to Fran, emacs -Q corrects the issue. I am using GUI. So, should I just always run emacs -Q, or is there a configuration I can adjust to permanently solve this?

Comment: Experiment some more: try `emacs -q` (no user init file) and `emacs --no-site-file` (no site-wide startup file).  Do one of these show the bad behaviour?  Do you have a `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults` file with emacs customisation in?  Edit this answer or yr original question to tell us more.

Comment: Instead of writing your comment as an answer, you should add it to the question: it is relevant information and the question should be as complete as possible. I suspect that one of the moderators will do that in any case, so you might want to go ahead and preempt them :-)